# Eclipse debug with MinGW: Failed to execute MI command

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I did a new installation of Eclipse Juno 32 bits, and a new installation of MinGW 32 bits, my platform is Windows 7 64 bits. When trying to debug a simple program I can watch very simple expressions, but everything more complicated gets me an error. For an example in the following program:

```
int main()
{
  vector<int> vRings;
  for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
    vRings.push_back(i%5);
  }
  //std::cout << "result:" << getRingNumber(vRings,vDiscs);
  return 0;
}
```

In the watch window, watching vRings work normally, but trying to watch the content of the vector doesn't work:

Trying to watch vRings[0]:

> Error: Multiple errors reported.\ Failed to execute MI command: -var-create - * 
>   vRings[0] Error message from debugger back end: Could not find
>   operator[].\ Unable to create variable object

Trying to watch vRings.at(0):

> vRings.at(0)  Error: Multiple errors reported.\ Failed to execute MI
>   command: -var-create - * vRings.at(0) Error message from debugger back
>   end: Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined\ Unable to create
>   variable object

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: It's an Eclipse never closed bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426202

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to watch the result of a function call.
Both `vRings.at()` and `vRings[]` are functions (the latter an overloaded function) that return a reference to a value. In your case - an integer.

If you want to watch the value of `vRings` at index 0, you can try to assign it to a variable at some point, for example:

```
int main()
{
      vector<int> vRings;
      for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
        vRings.push_back(i%5);
      }
      int watchme = vRings.at(0);
      //std::cout << "result:" << getRingNumber(vRings,vDiscs);
      return 0;
}
```

Then you can watch the variable `watchme`.

Comment: This requires to modify the code and is not acceptable. When working correctly, eclipse can display tte results of the function calls correctly.